# How to use firebase database using PHP and AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database and that is linked with a mobile app and a web app both. I am working on the web app and I am good with PHP and AJAX so I would like to know if there's anyway to use firebase database using PHP and AJAX or else, if there is any way to connect it with a SQLdatabase.

Comment: Firebase is a NoSQL cloud based database. Connecting it to a SQL database wouldn't make sense to me. Personally I see Firebase as a way of storing simple data which isn't necessarily co-related. Firebase can also provide authentication, and other features, so I see it as a solution for people coding for a lightweight app (as an alternative to running their own backend with a traditional RDBC) Could you provide more information as to what you aim to get out of "connecting" the two?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Firebase JS SDK from the javascript side of your web application.
For example, you may get an object from the Database (Realtime or Firestore), using an ID provided by your PHP code:

- set the value of JS variable with PHP:

```js
var itemid = <?php echo $user->itemid ?>
```

- use this JS var to get the "item" object from Firebase:

```js
// i.e. read once from Realtime Database
firebase.database().ref('items/' + itemid).once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    var item = snapshot.val();
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error.code));

// i.e. read once from Firestore
firebase.firestore().collection('items').doc(itemid).get()
  .then(doc => {
    var item = doc.exists ? doc.data() : null;
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```